# Transpose each row into a column in python (from a csv file)

Tags: python, transpose

I am trying to write a python code that does the following. Can someone help? Thank you!

Read each row in a csv file (file1), transpose it, and stack it into a single column in a new csv file (file2). File1 has data in 6 columns and 90 rows:
[please click here for an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FObq0.png)

Comment: It woud be helpful if you uplod your code you are struggling, so that other people can help you based on your understanding.

Comment: @SangkeunPark correct

Answer (score 0):

I'd first convert the csv to a list of lists -

```
import csv
with open(InputFile, 'r') as csvFile:
    list_of_lists = []        
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row_num, row in enumerate(reader):
        list_of_lists.append(row)
```

And then use this to re-arrange the elements.
For example, if your list looked like -

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
result = []
for i in list_of_lists:
    for j in i:
        result.append(j)
print(result)

# Output:
# [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Just adding a note that its not what transpose means.
Transpose would convert rows to columns and columns to rows

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as infile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',') # select your csv's delimiter
    out = []
    for row in csvreader:
        out.extend(row)
```

Now all your rows have been joined in 1 list. Now you can save it as a single column in a new csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that with *"6 columns and 90 rows"* of input, memory won't be an issue. So you could do:

```
import csv

with open("input.csv", "r") as fin, open("output.csv", "w") as fout:
    fout.write("\n".join(item for row in csv.reader(fin) for item in row))
```